# Angular: Wrap component with the private base href

Tags: angular

I have a component in Angular, which renders images.

f.e., it adds `<img src="/path/to/image">`

Lets imaging our application is located on http://host.name

We have relative pathes to images which don't contain host name. But it should show images from another host name..

So, in HTML we will just see `<img src="/path/to/image">`
But this image should be shown from http://host2.name/path/to/image

Can you help me with suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you only need to concatenate the relative paths to the host name and bind the variable to the `[src]` property.

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  imgPath = '/some/path/image.jpg';
  imgHost = 'http://hostname';
  imgSrc: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.imgSrc = this.imgHost + this.imgPath;
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<img [src]="imgSrc">
```

Comment: sorry, no

we are not able to change html. it's like this ```<img src="/path/to/image">```

Comment: So, I just need to change base-href for images which are located in appropriate component (not to change base-href for a whole app)

Comment: A quick solution would be to fetch all the `img` elements from the template and set it's `src` property in the controller.